# pg_dumpall | ssh username@server 'cat > alldb.sql'

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

Im trying to dump my local postgresql database to remote server but

```
pg_dumpall | ssh username@server 'cat > alldb.sql'
```

output

pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Already tried

```
postgres=# psql -f alldb.sql postgres
```

no output

Also

```
postgres@iitians:/home/iitians$ psql -f alldb.sql postgres
```

but no output

Comment: Is the server running on port 5432 on the same machine on which you are running pg_dumpall?

Comment: it is remote server and i have backup of postgresql database on my local

Comment: login on your remote DB server, then try to use: "pg_dumpall -U user > backup.sql" then "cat backup.sql | psql -U user database" ..maybe there is something related by Jeremy comment